# getElementById with variable into backticks

Tags: javascript

I want to modify an element according to the id that returns my server, out after several hours of research I can not operate my code.

```
var doc = document.getElementById(`"itvf-ticket-${data.idIntervention}"`);
console.log(doc); --> null
doc.style.display = "block"; --> can't work cause it's null
```

Yet if I enter my id directly, the "display block" is made.

```
document.getElementById("itvf-ticket-36").style.display = "block";
```

Thank's!

Comment: What, if anything, is processing those backticks? Or are you trying to use a template literal?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using backticks then the quotation marks aren't necessary and can be removed.

```
var doc = document.getElementById(`itvf-ticket-${data.idIntervention}`);
```

See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for template literals for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using backticks because you're trying to use a template literal, the problem is the quotes (`"`); remove them:

```
var doc = document.getElementById(`itvf-ticket-${data.idIntervention}`);
doc.style.display = "block";
```

An untagged template literal results in a string.

Live Example:

```js
var data = {
  idIntervention: "123"
};
var doc = document.getElementById(`itvf-ticket-${data.idIntervention}`);
doc.style.display = "block";
```

```html
<div id="itvf-ticket-123" style="display: none">This is the initially-hidden div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the string you are generating. Compare it to the working string.

```js
const manual = "itvf-ticket-36";
const data = {
  idIntervention: 36
};
const generated = `"itvf-ticket-${data.idIntervention}"`;
console.log(manual);
console.log(generated);
console.log(manual === generated);
```

`"` delimit a string literal. `` ` `` delimit a template literal which creates a string.

You are adding quote marks to the ID you are trying to search for. Don't put the quote marks inside your string:

```
const generated = `itvf-ticket-${data.idIntervention}`;
```